# How to handle fetch API AJAX response in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, response, fetch-api

I am making a simple AJAX request with the fetch API in React, specifically in the `componentDidMount()` function.

It is working, because the console appears to be logging the result. However, I don't know how to access the response...

```
componentDidMount = () => {

      let URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'

         fetch(URL)
         .then(function(response) {
            let myData = response.json()
            return myData;
         })
         .then(function(json) {
            console.log('parsed json', json)
         })
         .catch(function(ex) {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
         })

   } // end componentDidMount
```

I tried accessing `myData` outside of the fetch method, but this throws an error saying that it is undefined. So it is only accessible within the scope of the function.

I then tried this:

```
     .then(function(response) {
        let myData = response.json()
        // return myData;
        this.setState({
           data: myData
        })
     })
```

This time, I get `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined(…)`

How do I pass the fetch response to the state, or even just a global variable?

---

### UPDATE

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         data: null
      }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      let URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'  
         fetch(URL)
         .then( (response) => {
            let myData = response.json()
            // return myData;
            this.setState({
               data: myData
            })
         })
         .then( (json) => {
            console.log('parsed json', json)
         })
         .catch( (ex) => {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
         })
         console.log(this.state.data)
   } // end componentDidMount

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         {this.state.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 13):

You have two issues as far as I can see, `response.json()` returns a promise, so you don't wanna set `myData` to the promise, instead first resolve the promise and then you can access your data.

Second, `this` is not in the same scope inside your fetch request, so that's why you are getting undefined, you can try saving the scope of `this` outside fetch:

```
var component = this;

fetch(URL)
 .then( (response) => {
    return response.json()    
 })
 .then( (json) => {
    component.setState({
       data: json
    })
    console.log('parsed json', json)
 })
 .catch( (ex) => {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
 })
 console.log(this.state.data)
```

Comment: thnx alot dude! i wasted 3 hours for this

Answer (score 7):

setState is undefined, because you use classic function syntax instead arrow function. Arrow function takes 'this' keyword from 'parent' function, a classic function() {} creates it's own 'this' keyword.
Try this

```
.then(response => {
    let myData = response.json()
    // return myData;
    this.setState({
       data: myData
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with `this.setState` however `this` is no longer in the context of the component when you call it within the function handling the response.  Using a `=>` function maintains the context of `this`.

```
fetch(URL)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => this.setState({data: json}));
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, but I'm still not getting the desired result. Please take a look at my update...

Comment: You're still referencing `this` in the context of the response handler and not the context of the component.  You either need to bind the component to your function or use a fat arrow function in order to maintain the context of this.

Comment: I see your update now.  You've now declared `componentDidMount` with an arrow function.  This essentially breaks your component because now `this` inside that arrow function is no longer in the context of the component.  You should declare it like `componentDidMount() {}` like you had before.  The response handler from the fetch response is the one that needs to use the arrow function.

Comment: Still not working :/ Have changed my update... `myData` is still holding the `null` value I declared in the state initialisation...

Comment: Have you tried rendering `this.state.data` in your `render()` method?  Once you call `this.setState({data: myData})`, it will trigger a render of your component.  Also, if you're using Chrome, you can debug this using the React Devtools Chrome extension.  It will allow you to see the state of your component after the call to `this.setState({data: myData})`.

Comment: Yep, tried that, still doesn't work unfortunately. I'll see what I can do with Chrome React Devtools...

Comment: It would be worth seeing your full component at this point.  Maybe there's something there that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Having never used the `fetch` API, I think I've found the problem.  calling `response.json()` doesn't actually return JSON, it returns a `Promise`.  So the place to put your `this.setState` is in the return from that promise.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**REACT NATIVE**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class SampleApp extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    data:  'Request '
    }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
fetch('http://localhost/replymsg.json', {
                      mode: "no-cors",
                      method: "GET",
                      headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                      },} )
                      .then(response => {
                      if (response.ok) {

                          response.json().then(json => {

                            console.warn( JSON.stringify(json.msg ));
                              this.setState({
                                 data: JSON.stringify(json)
                            })

                        });
                      }
                    }); 

}



render() { 
return (
    <Text>  {this.state.data}</Text>
    );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

**JSON FILE**
create a file replymsg.json and put below content and it should host to local host like : http://localhost/replymsg.json

```
{"status":"200ok","CurrentID":28,"msg":"msg successfully reply"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you access the response data by using '=>' instead of function to be in the same context.

```
componentDidMount = () => {

      let URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'

         fetch(URL)
         .then(function(response) {
            let myData = response.json()
            return myData;
         })
         .then((json) => {
            console.log('parsed json', json)
         })
         .catch(function(ex) {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
         })

} // end componentDidMount
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind current context to the target function

```
fetch(URL)
         .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
         })
         .then(function(json) {
            this.setState({data: json})
         }.bind(this))
         .catch(function(ex) {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
         })
```